# Can I retrieve only certain fields from Windows Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have the following class:

```
public class Menu : TableServiceEntity
{

    public string Order { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int    Length { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to retrieve only the PartitionKey, RowKey, Order and Length data from my TableStorage.

Is there some way that I can just retrieve this data or do I still need to retrieve everything. The reason I ask is because the Text field contains some large amounts of data and I would like to minimize what is retrieved to just what I need.

Please note this is **not** SQL Azure storage. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the 2011-08-18 version you can use the query projection (LINQ Select).

```
var context = cloudTableClient.GetDataServiceContext();
context.CreateQuery<Menu>().Select(...);
```

Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135725.aspx

Comment: Remember to use **always** the PartitionKey to maximize the query performance.

Comment: What do you mean by "using" PartitionKey - do you mean that I should not have queries without it?